# Convex Optimization:Optimality of Point on Boundary

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider a standard form convex optimization problem: $\min_x f(x)$ with the convex constraints $g_i(x) \leq 0$ for all $i \in [p],$ and a convex objective function $f.$  If it helps any, $f$ can be assumed monotone increasing/decreasing as well.

Suppose there exists a point $\tilde{x}$ such that $g_i(\tilde{x}) = 0,$ and there is no point $x^\prime$ in the neighborhood of $\tilde{x}$ and in the interior of the feasible set such that $f(x^\prime) \leq f(\tilde{x}).$  Is this sufficient to claim that any optimizer of the problem satisfies the $i$'th inequality constraint at optimality, i.e. does the optimizer $x^\star$ satisfy $g_i(x^*) = 0 necessarily?

My gut says "no,'' but I can't seem to construct a counter example analytically.  This doesn't *appear* to break the KKT conditions, for example.  But it also does not seem to be implied by them, either.

For context: Attempting to use a convex optimization problem to find a feasible point of a nonconvex set.  Finding a convex superset of the set in question is easy, as is finding an objective function which would guarantee my above-mentioned property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any conditions on $f$? (E.g. is it convex?)

Comment: Yes, $f$ is convex.  I'll edit the post to make that explicit, had only made that declaration implicit through calling it a convex problem, sorry!

Comment: Isn't $\tilde x$ a strict local minimizer? For a convex problem, local and global minimizer agree.

Comment: In an unconstrained problem, yes, for sure.  The gradient of the objective function would have to be $0$ for my claim to be true.

For a constrained problem, conceivably one can descend along the boundary of the set (think projected gradient method).  Note that I'm only claiming that any point in the neighborhood of $\tilde{x}$ *and* in the *interior* of the feasible set has a worse objective value.

Comment: @notwatson local minimizer of a convex function function on a convex set is also global. The proof is elementary, no need for gradients.

Comment: @user251257 The point $\tilde{x}$ is not necessarily a local minimizer, however.  It may decrease by moving on the boundary of the set, or at least I haven't been able to rule that out in my particular problem.

The condition I'm guaranteeing is that I cannot enter the proper interior of the set without increasing the objective.  I do not believe that implies that there is no direction of descent on the boundary itself.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? If it is, just employ a limit argument. Notice that a convex function on a finite dimensional open domain is continuous.